# Eliminar basura de un array

Tags: javascript, json, array, local-storage

Tengo el siguiente código: lo que trato de hacer es que cuando un usuario nuevo quiere registrarse en mi proyecto debe llenar el formulario **3 veces** una vez **enviado 3 veces** recién el registro sera **exitoso**. Por ese motivo uso `localStorage` para guardar los datos del primer, segundo y tercer envio del formulario.

El código que presento en realidad es una abstracción (minimo, completo y verificable) de mi código real (sería mucho código).

***El código que publico no funciona en SOes (no sé por qué), pruébenlo de manera local por favor.***

```js
var nombreAux = "";
var apellidoAux = "";
var dato_G = []; //tiempo de presion y realce
var dato_aux = [];

var iteracion = 0;

$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('#add-new-fact').click(function () {
        var nombreUser = $('#nom').val();
        var passUser = $('#pass').val();
        var dato = $('#dato').val();
        dato_aux.push(dato);

        if (nombreUser != "" && passUser != "") {

            /*Guardando los datos en el LocalStorage*/
            nombreAux = localStorage.getItem("Nombre");
            apellidoAux = localStorage.getItem("contrasena");
            // alert(nombreAux+" "+apellidoAux);
            if ((nombreAux == "" || apellidoAux == "")) {
                localStorage.setItem("Nombre", nombreUser);
                localStorage.setItem("contrasena", passUser);
            }
            nombreAux = localStorage.getItem("Nombre");
            apellidoAux = localStorage.getItem("contrasena");

            if (((nombreUser != nombreAux || passUser != apellidoAux))) { //cuando es nuevo user
                localStorage.setItem("Nombre", nombreUser);
                localStorage.setItem("contrasena", passUser);
                dato_G.push(JSON.stringify(dato_aux));
                localStorage['dato'] = dato_G;
                dato = [];
            }

            if ((nombreUser == nombreAux || passUser == apellidoAux) && (iteracion < 6) && (typeof dato != undefined)) { //cuando ya es un usuario
                iteracion++;
                if (dato.length > 0) {
                    dato_G.push(JSON.stringify(localStorage['dato']));
                    dato_G.push(JSON.stringify(dato_aux));
                    dato_aux = [];
                }

                localStorage['dato'] = dato_G;
            }

            alert(localStorage['dato']);

            location.reload();

            if (iteracion == 3) {

                //por medio de ajax recien envio los datos para su registro en la BD

            }
            return false;

        }
        alert(localStorage['dato']);
        nombreUser = "";
        passUser = "";
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="nom" type="text" placeholder="nombre">
<input id="pass" type="text" placeholder="pass">
<input id="dato" type="text" placeholder="dato">
<a href="#" id="add-new-fact" >enviar</a>

</body>
</html>
```

El resultado me genera un `array` "infectado" o con basura, parecido al screenshot de abajo:

[image]

Quisiera quedarme solamente con los `arrays`. ¿Será posible?

***Nota:*** a medida que se va insertando `array` se va llenando de mas basura.

¿Cómo evitar esa basura? ¿Por qué se genera?

Comment: ¿De dónde vienen esas barras de escape? ¿Cómo de están generando? Tengo la sensación de que estás tratando de generar una solución alternativa en vez de atacar el problema de raíz

Comment: Estoy ebrio, así que si omito algo de tu code, lo siento xD. Si necesitas guardar arrays en local/session storage, solo necesitas agregarlos a un objeto y guardar éste objeto como string mediante `JSON.stringify` y recuperarlo mediante `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mydata'));`. De ésta manera aseguras el formato del objeto.

Comment: El código no se puede ejecutar en Stack Snippet porque este no permite el uso de localStorage. Ref. [Why are we disallowed to use HTML5 local storage on code snippets?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345385/1595451), además, el código carga un archivo "main.js" lo cual no es posible hacer en Stack Snippet, por estas razones en un momento removeré Stack Snippet

Answer (score 3):

Honestamente, me mareo un poco intentando interpretar el código, por lo que voy a publicar una respuesta parcial, esperando que te sirva.

El problema es que estás utilizando `JSON.stringify()` sobre una variable que ya es un JSON, por lo que termina escapando los caracteres más de una vez.

Para solucionarlo, al manipular el valor de `dato`, no intentes convertirlo de/a JSON en la parte principal de tu código, manejalo como objeto sin convertirlo. Y, luego, la conversión se haría sólo al momento de guardar o leer de localStorage.

```
function recuperarDato(clave) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(clave));
}

function guardarDato(clave, objeto) {
    localStorage.setItem(clave, JSON.stringify(objeto));
}
```

Así, para guardar:

```
guardarDato("dato", dato_G);
```

Y para leerlo:

```
dato_G = recuperarDato("dato");
```

Comment: Es sólo una recomendación, pero creo que podría ayudarte a que sea más sencillo y evitar este tipo de problemas

Answer (score 1):

para solucionar mi problema tuve que utilizar `JSON.stringify` y `JSON.parse`, y no asi solamente `JSON.stringify()` como postee en la pregunta.

```
 var nombreAux   = "";
    var apellidoAux ="";
    var dato_G= []; //tiempo de presion y realce
    var dato_aux=[];

var iteracion=0;


$(window).on('load', function() {  
    $('#add-new-fact').click(function() {
    var nombreUser = $('#nom').val();
    var passUser = $('#pass').val();
    var dato = $('#dato').val();
    dato_aux.push(dato);

if(nombreUser!="" && passUser!=""){

/*Guardando los datos en el LocalStorage*/
    nombreAux   = localStorage.getItem("Nombre");
    apellidoAux = localStorage.getItem("contrasena");
// alert(nombreAux+" "+apellidoAux);
   if((nombreAux==""||apellidoAux=="")){
        localStorage.setItem("Nombre", nombreUser);
        localStorage.setItem("contrasena", passUser);
    }
    nombreAux   = localStorage.getItem("Nombre");
    apellidoAux = localStorage.getItem("contrasena");

    if(((nombreUser!=nombreAux || passUser!=apellidoAux))){//cuando es nuevo user
        localStorage.setItem("Nombre", nombreUser);
        localStorage.setItem("contrasena", passUser);
        dato_G.push(JSON.stringify(dato_aux));
        localStorage['dato']=JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(dato_G));
        dato=[];
    }

    if((nombreUser==nombreAux || passUser==apellidoAux) && (iteracion<3) &&(typeof dato!=undefined) ){//cuando ya es un usuario 
        iteracion++;
        if(dato.length>0){
            dato_G.push(localStorage['dato']);
            dato_G.push(JSON.stringify(dato_aux));
            dato_aux=[];    
        }

        localStorage['dato']=dato_G; 
  }

    alert(localStorage['dato']);

location.reload();

if(iteracion==3){
alert("enviando");
    //por medio de ajax recien envio los datos para su registro en la BD

}
    return false;

}
alert(localStorage['dato']);
    nombreUser="";
    passUser="";
  });

});
```

Comment: Una sola cosa: no le entiendo la lógica a `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(dato_G))`... Eso es lo mismo que `dato_G` (vuelve al valor original). Las funciones son exactamente inversas entre sí

Comment: @Mariano lo puse asi para obtener en arreglo, lo testeare mejor, lo publique a la rapida, por la alegria :)